# How to remove extra padding/inner margin from PhpSpreadsheet column autosize?

Tags: php, excel, padding, phpspreadsheet, autosize

I was looking for answer everywhere and I still have no clue what can I do. I'm using this code to set autosize:

```
for($col = 'A'; $col !== 'S'; $col++)
{
    $xlsx->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

But as you see I have a lot of columns, so I need to put them as tightly as possible. Unfortunately, when I'm using this code above some extra padding is being added to some columns. When I open my Excel file I can easily click autosize button and after this extra padding is being removed. What can I do to export my file without this padding?

See here how it looks like when I export it from my website and what's the difference after clicking autosize directly in my file.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Hitting the same problem myself just now.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score -1):

use auto size.

Read section - Setting a column's width.
This will automatically select the width you need.

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
```

Comment: If you look at my code, you will see that I am actually using autosize

Comment: @Kida, sorrry, use function setIndent(). it is in the documentation and examples

Comment: I see I can add a padding with `setIndent()` but I can't remove padding using this